# Joomla Database Error: Unable to connect

Tags: php, joomla

I have a hosting account on http://cpanel.byethost22.com  . After I login to my vista panel, in the account information page it says that my Home Path is->

/home/vol3/byethost22.com/b22_10132649

And when I go to my file manager, a page shows up where I need to click on htdocs to see all my files.

Now the problem is I am trying to make a joomla website live on the host so I provided the following information in configuration.php file of joomla but when I hit my address ( http://sharkerection.byethost22.com ) on the browser it says "Database Error: Unable to connect to the database:Could not connect to MySQL"

```
var $log_path = '/home/vol3/byethost22.com/b22_10132649/htdocs/logs';
var $tmp_path = '/home/vol3/byethost22.com/b22_10132649/htdocs/tmp';
var $host = 'http://sharkerection.byethost22.com';
var $smtphost = 'localhost';
```

My Database username, password and database type.. all are correct but still its not working.

Could you please tell me if the problem is in var $log_path,var $tmp_path,var $host,var $smtphost

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Check your db name & is that db is assign to that particular user ?

Comment: @Rikesh Shah Thanks for your reply. My DB name is correct and my host doesn't offer assigning any user to the db(using free package). Do you think the value of $log_path I am using is correct? Thanks again :)

Comment: @black_belt the value of the log-path is irrelevant. show us the lines of the connection string (no need to include the real username/password)

Comment: @alfasin Thanks for your reply. I already got my solution. thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting

```
$host = 'localhost';
```

The variable $host should not be the url to your site, but the address to your database.

Comment: Thanks :) I changed the value of $host to the link to my database and then I used var $log_path = '/htdocs/logs '; var $tmp_path = '/htdocs/tmp'; . Its working now. Thanks again.:)